# copy *.html file from a remote system

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I would like to copy *.html files from a directory path "C:\abc\xyz\" on my system. I have created a shared folder on my system and I am having the domain admin rights into my user account. I have created a `.bat` file and commands inside the `.bat` file is as follows:

```
pushd \\Target-Hostname\c$\abc\xyz\
xcopy *.html \\Shared-Folder-Path\ /s/e/h/q
popd
```

However, I get an error "Invalid drive specification". May I know why this error arises? How can alter the command in a .bat file? There are around 100 systems from which I need to copy *.html files (Note: file path on remote systems will remain the same).

Can I copy *.html files by using a VBScript that will execute on a network having domain setup?

Comment: `\\servername\sharename\folder\file` You are missing the double slash `\\`.

Comment: No, I guess it went missing while copy pasting the command here. The share name is correctly mentioned with double slash in my .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

UNC paths consist of at least the names of a host and a share on that host, optionally followed by a path below that share:

```
\\server\share[\sub\folder]
```

An UNC path `\\share\` is invalid, which is what `xcopy` is telling you.

Also, if you're copying from remote systems to a local folder you don't need an UNC path for the destination in the first place. Simply use the local path:

```cmd
xcopy \\Target-Hostname\c$\abc\xyz\*.html C:\local\folder /s/e/h/q
```

Of course you can do the same in VBScript:

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile "\\Target-Hostname\c$\abc\xyz\*.html" "C:\local\folder\"
```

but just changing the language wouldn't have addressed the misconception in your approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this solution soon.